# Unable to retrieve ads form airpush

Tags: android, android-manifest, airpush

Got myself newly registered on AirPush. I integrated bundle SDK with my App. When I tested it for the first time, I got a couple of impressions. It also shows 2 impressions on dashboard.

Now I am unable to fetch the impressions. Did contact the developer team but to no avail.

My code of MainActivity goes like this :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // MMSDK.initialize(this);

    //  setup a new adView and initialize an adRequest to it.


    setupAirPushAdView();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    }


    try {

        if (!appStarted) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            appStarted = true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getClass().toString() + "\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            perform();
        }
    }, 2000);



}

private void perform() {


    setContentView(R.layout.app_home);

    if (!appStarted) {

        // attachAdView();

        attachAirPushAdView();
        appStarted = true;
    }
...
```

Other Methods :

```
private void setupAirPushAdView() {

    ma = new MA(this, null, false);

    airPushAdView = new AdView(this, AdView.BANNER_TYPE_IN_APP_AD, AdView.PLACEMENT_TYPE_INTERSTITIAL, false, false,
            AdView.ANIMATION_TYPE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

}

private void attachAirPushAdView() {

    LinearLayout outerAdLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.externalAdId);
    outerAdLayout.addView(airPushAdView);

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />




<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />





<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>   
<!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" -->
<!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" -->
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="differential_activity"

    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
    >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="integral_activity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="equation_activity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <!--  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="nosensor" -->
    <!-- for all activities -->            


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.APPID" android:value="206488" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.APIKEY" android:value="android*1392147786176500813"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.BrowserActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.VActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity> 
    <service android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.LService" android:exported="false"></service>
    <receiver android:name="com.gyesa.keanp176500.BootReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



</application>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />


</manifest>
```

Comment: Read this maybe it will help you: http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Bundle_SDK_1.0_Documentation#Ad_Units